# How to cancel chooseDesktopMedia?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, webrtc, getusermedia, screensharing, desktop-sharing

In my web page, there is a screen sharing stream, the following are the parameters:

```js
{
    audio: false,
    video: mandatory {
               chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
               chromeMediaSourceId: IM.screenSourceId
              ...
           }
     ...
}
```

My Chrome extension contains the following code in the background script:

```js
desktop_id = chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia (session, port.sender.tab, onAccessApproved);
```

When click the "Cancel" button on the page, the listener function in the background script is triggered:

```js
chrome.desktopCapture.cancelChooseDesktopMedia (desktop_id);
```

In `chrome://extensions` of `console.log` to see `desktop_id` really is an integer value of `1`.

But it seems does not work, I tried many Chrome versions but it still does not work, what should I do to cancel the screen sharing?

Answer (score 2):

[`chrome.desktopCapture.cancelChooseDesktopMedia`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture#method-cancelChooseDesktopMedia) closes the chooser dialog if it is still open. It does NOT stop the media stream after the user has choosen a target for recording.

If you want to stop recording the screen, call the `.stop()` method of the media stream instead. E.g.

```js
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({
    audio: false,
    video: {
        mandatory: {
            chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
            chromeMediaSourceId: IM.screenSourceId
        }   
    }   
}, function onSuccess(stream) {
    // Example: end the recording after 10 seconds.
    setTimeout(function() {
        stream.stop();
    }, 10000);
}, function onError() {
    // Handle error
});
```